# Sending emails to Microsoft teams channel does not keep css format

Tags: outlook, office365, microsoft-teams

I set up a channel where I sent an email with a specific css. In outlook I can see the message perfectly, but the channel does not display any colour. 
I even added the css with classes and id tags into the html file, but it does not work.

Example: 
The message is something like:

```
<html>
   <head>
    <script src= 'https://statics.teams.cdn.office.net/sdk/v1.6.0/js/MicrosoftTeams.min.js'></script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
    <style type="text/css">
    #first{ color: orange; }
    #secondLine {
      background-color: lightblue;
      color: red;
    }
    .override {color: green;}
    </style>
   </head>
   <body>
      <script>
    microsoftTeams.initialize();
      </script>
      <p class="override">Hi there,</p>
      <p id="first"> First line:test.</p>
      <p id="secondLine">Second line Another test.</p>
      <p style="color:blue">Best Regards.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

In outlook:

[image]

In Microsoft Teams channel:

[image]

I think that maybe it can not display the colour due to a css conflict with Microsoft teams css. If it is the case, could I override it?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Are you trying to send mail using bot or graph API? Could you please share more details.

Comment: I am sending the email using a python script which generates a html file posted into the description. Then I use a smtp and email libraries to send this file into the body of the email.

Comment: we could able to reproduce the issue on our side. Raised a bug.

Comment: so, any suggestion? @Nikitha-MSFT

Comment: Could you please try sending mail using Graph API? Here is the docs for [Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-sendmail?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http)

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT I observed that Teams totally removes the `<style>...</style>` keeping no room for custom styles. Can you please suggest something over it?

Comment: @saurabh - Did you try graph API?

Answer (score 0):

Due to the need to make sure Teams theming and other display constraint in channel works with content mailed into channel, we do not promise to preserve arbitrary HTML / CSS structure inside the email. If complex format is needed in the post, we usually ask users to author them directly in Teams instead of relying on our email to channel logic to preserve them.

We already try to preserve as much formatting as possible without affecting the overall Teams themes. This is by design.